# Cannot import statsmodel module because it doesn't show it's installed

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I tried importing the statsmodel in jupyter notebook. It showed the error that the module was not found. I searched on this site and on the net in general and tried a few options but to no avail. I tried installing pip and conda in Anaconda prompt and Jupyter Notebook. I am not a regular developer so forgive me if I missed something obvious. I have attached the images of the errors for better understanding. My Python is 3.7.4 version.

Image 1 - Anaconda Prompt pip and conda install attempts
Image 2 - Statsmodel showing up in pip list command
Image 3 - Conda Jupyter Notebook Install Error
Image 4 - Pip Jupyter Notebook Install Error
Image 5 - Statsmodel folder in Anaconda3>Lib>Site-Packages

[image: Anaconda Prompt pip and conda install attempts]

[image: Statsmodel showing up in pip list command]

[image: Conda Jupyter Notebook Install Error]

[image: Pip Jupyter Notebook Install Error]

[image: Statsmodel folder in Anaconda3>Lib>Site-Packages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pip install statsmodels` instead of `pip install statsmodel`.

The reason you are getting these errors is because you are trying to install a package which does not exist.

Also in order to test whether the installation went successfully: `import statsmodels`